# Is it possible to make fixable errors/warnings with SwiftLint?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, swiftlint

I'm using SwiftLint to make custom errors and warnings and it's working well.

However, **I want to add a "fix" button to the warnings and errors** just like with standard Xcode errors and warnings.

Xcode already does this for the internal warnings/errors, like this:

[image]

Here's what my current custom warning looks like:

[image]

I've scoured through the documentation, tutorials, etc. and also opened an issue here:

https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/issues/3315

I don't think it exists with SwiftLint, but I'd love to know if anybody can be prove me wrong or know of a better alternative!

P.S. Here's a link to their repo: https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint

Comment: Out of curiosity, what’s an example of your custom warning.

Comment: @valosip Added an image of it on the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered here by SwiftLint owners: https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/issues/3315